# how to make a Yad split window, upper split = text and lower split = progress bar?

Tags: gui, yad

I can't work out how to make a Yad split window, upper split = text and lower split = progress bar? My attempt below failed.

```
id=$(echo $[($RANDOM % ($[10000 - 32000] + 1)) + 10000] )
Settings=$(cat ~/tmp/YadWindow4SelectedSettings.txt)

{
echo 25
echo "#25%"
echo 50
echo "#50%"
echo 75
echo "#75%"
echo 100
echo "#100%"
} |
yad --plug=$id --tabnum=1 --progress --auto-close --auto-kill --center --width=700 --image=$ICON --image-on-top --title="Loading..." --percentage=0 &> res1 &
yad --plug=$id --tabnum=2 --text="$Settings" &> res2 &
yad --length=800 --width=800 --center --paned --key=$id --splitter="200"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been helped elsewhere with advice on an alternative method for the same result. Using this I wrote the following, which seems to work sufficiently for me:

```
Settings=$(cat ~/tmp/YadWindow4SelectedSettings.txt)

{
echo 25
echo "#25%"
sleep 2
echo 50
echo "#50%"
sleep 2
echo 75
echo "#75%"
sleep 2
echo 100
echo "#100%"
} |
yad --progress --enable-log --log-on-top --log-expanded --auto-close --auto-kill --center --width=700 --image=$ICON --image-on-top --title="Loading..." --text="$Settings" --percentage=0
```